# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './Sidebar/SideBar' Webpack Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

Trying to deploy to heroku but I am getting an error in my console:
Main.js:4 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './Sidebar/SideBar'
at webpackMissingModule (Main.js:4)

./Sidebar/SideBar is a React component. I have deployed this app to Heroku before without issue. Also, usually after "deploying" the first load works but the second does not.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new MinifyPlugin()],
  },
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './client/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new CompressionPlugin()],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "slack-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A slack clone",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev",
    "start": "npm run start-server & npm run build-watch",
    "start-server": "nodemon server -w server",
    "build-watch": "webpack -w",
    "deploy": "script/deploy",
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "seed": "node seed.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.0",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^3.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-expand-animated": "^1.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^5.7.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-resizable": "^1.10.1",
    "react-resize-panel": "^0.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.0",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.15.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `'./Sidebar/SideBar'` may be the issue is with naming. Check that you have exactly same component name. Specially the camel case

Comment: Hey! Thanks for getting back. The spelling was off however. It was looking for ./Sidebar/SideBar but was actually ./SideBar/Sidebar

Comment: I changed it so now both cases are spelled ./SideBar/SideBar but I still is getting the error but with the spelling updated.

Comment: can you please share your error log

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './SideBar/SideBar'
    at webpackMissingModule (Main.js:4)
    at Object../client/components/Main.js (Main.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../client/components/index.js (bundle.js:1863)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../client/index.js (index.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (index.js:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83

Comment: Definitely its your import issue. Check your folder Name is `SideBar` and your component name is `SideBar`. And if possible show the tree view of your project and main.js

Comment: Hmm Just tried renamed my folder to SideBarMain and it is consistently loading, awhile still a bit skeptical haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218636/discussion-between-monzoor-tamal-and-bleepbloopbleep).